# loop not printing what is required

Tags: java, selenium, loops, for-loop, arraylist

Here is my code:

```
for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection) {
List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
   int col_num = 1;
   String rowHeader = "<tr>";
        for(WebElement tdElement : td_collection) {
            rows += "<td>"+tdElement.getText()+"</td>";
            col_num++;   
        }
        String rowFooter = "</tr>\r\n";
        row_num++;
        scrape = rowHeader + rows + rowFooter+"\n\n"; 
}
```

The output is:

```
<tr><td>Airi Satou</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>33</td><td>2008/11/28</td><td>$162,700</td><td>Angelica Ramos</td><td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td><td>London</td><td>47</td><td>2009/10/09</td><td>$1,200,000</td></tr>
```

The loop is reading `rowFooter` and `rowHeader` for the first & last iteration whereas I am trying to print `TR` at starting of the row and when all `TDS` are fetched then at the end of the row as well as in the same way for all rows of the table.

Why `scrape = rowHeader + rows + rowFooter+"\n\n";` is not printing as required?

**Update**
When I print without `String` values by using `System.out.println()` then its working fine:

```
for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection)
        {
            List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
            col_num=1;
            System.out.println("<tr>");
            for(WebElement tdElement : td_collection)
            {
               System.out.println("<td>"+tdElement.getText()+"</td>\r\n");
               col_num++;
            }
            System.out.println("</tr>");
            row_num++;
        }
```

Comment: By.xpath("./td")  try that. To get child elements from a parent using xpath we use .  to access them.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan sorry I was testing another class that was printing with `System.out.println`. Not worked !!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @User169 : Why `scrape = rowHeader + rows + rowFooter+"\n\n";` is not printing as required? what is expected and actual value? where did you declare `scrape` variable?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan @KunduK The expected output is `<tr><td>all tds</td><td>one by one and at the end of each row TR</td></tr> whereas its printing <tr><td></td>NOT closing row with TR and iterating at the end without TR  closing tag. Only prints TR at start and end of loop

Answer (score 0):

```
By.xpath("./td")
```

To access a child element of trElement we use the . for xpaths only while using /tr to access all the tds that are exactly one element deep nested.